# Inquietud con método actualizar de JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

me gustaría saber por que este codigo JSON no me esta actualizandoQU los registros. De antemano muchas Gracias

```
     router.put('/conductor/:conductorId',(req, res, next) => {
  
      let conductorRutaId = req.params.conductorId

      let conductorUpdate = req.body
    
      Conductor.findByIdAndUpdate(conductorId, conductorUpdate, (err, conductorUpdated) => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al actualizar el registro del conductor: ${err}`})
    
        res.status(200).send({conductor:conductorUpdated })
      });
    });
```

A continuación pantallazo cuando hago la prueba en POSTMAN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: abre el inspectordel navegador y muestra el error que arroja

Comment: ¿Json? ¿Te faltó agregarlo?

Comment: Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con Postman, y cuando actualizo un registro no pasa nada, es como si me listara el registro po ID

Comment: agrega el código que tienes en la función `findByIdAndUpdate`

Comment: en el ejemplo de mongoose dice que es algo como `Conductor.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: conductorUpdated }, options, callback)`

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás devolviendo al cliente el resultado que corresponde a la primera consulta (`findById`).

Según la documentación de Mongoose, el método [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) realiza lo siguiente:

1. Hace una búsqueda en la colección usando como `query` el campo `_id` del documento.
2. Actualiza el documento de acuerdo a los parámetros de actualización que correspondan.
3. Devuelve el documento encontrado (si acaso hubo) y lo pasa a la función `callback`.

Por lo tanto, estás recibiendo en el `callback` el documento original que aún no ha sido modificado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para solventar el problema, debes usar un objeto con la opción adecuada que pasarás como argumento al método `findByIdAndUpdate`.

Dicha opción es: `new: true`.

Con esta opción, le estás diciendo a Mongoose que en vez de devolver el documento encontrado por `findById`, devuelva el documento modificado por `Update` (es decir, que devuelva el *nuevo* documento).

Por defecto el valor de `new` es `false`, y por ello, si no lo especificamos, siempre nos devolverá el documento encontrado antes de modificar.

Con esto tu código puede quedar así:

```
router.put('/conductor/:conductorId',(req, res, next) => {
    let conductorRutaId = req.params.conductorId;
    let conductorUpdate = req.body;
    // pasamos el objeto {new: true} como parámetro adicional
    Conductor.findByIdAndUpdate(conductorId, conductorUpdate, {new: true}, (err, conductorUpdated) => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al actualizar el registro del conductor: ${err}`});

        res.status(200).send({conductor:conductorUpdated });
    });
});
```

Espero que esta sea la respuesta que esperabas.